# How does Windows Task Manager calculate "In Use" memory

Tags: windows, memory, taskmanager

I am writing a tool in which I'd like to display the "in use" memory measurement, the way it's done in Windows Task Manager (on the "Performance" tab, under "Memory").

I can't seem to find a performance counter which matches up to this measure.

Can anyone explain how this metric is computed?

Comment: Which Windows, Windows 10?

Comment: Win 10 or Server 2016

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039693/270348