# why task manager 'In use' memory is more than all process consumed memory?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-leaks, operating-system, taskmanager

I am writing a real-time processing application and it allocates a lot of memory and release them properly.

memory consumption of my app is ok and it hasn't any leakage after a long period, but I encounter another problem.

my server has 64 Gb memory.

before my application starts to work, the task manager shows it has 5 GB memory 'In use', after 10 hours running my application, the task manager shows my app consumes 10 GB memory but the task manager shows the server has **60 GB** memory in use.

when I terminate my application 'In use' memory goes down as 10 GB and shows 50 GB.

furthermore, when I see 'User' tab of task manager, it shows 12 GB memory usage.

Now I want to know the difference between task manager 'In use' memory usage(60 GB) and my process memory usage( user memory usage 12 GB) origins from what? and how can I confront it? is there any memory management point that I forget to apply?

because memory 'In use' growth until it reaches memory capacity, server performance will be reduced in a while.

what is this additional memory usage in the task manager 'in use' section?

I read below similar questions on StackOverflow but I didn't receive my answer clearly.

[How does Windows Task Manager calculate "In Use" memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768573/how-does-windows-task-manager-calculate-in-use-memory)

[Accessing CPU/RAM usage (like with Task Manager, but via API!)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039466/accessing-cpu-ram-usage-like-with-task-manager-but-via-api)

I watched this observation in Windows server 2016/2019 and Windows 10.

I can't take a screenshot from the server now, so I take a screenshot from my pc and show related part in the below images. as you could see I have similar problem in my pc and there is a difference in user memory usage(1105MB) and task manager 'In use' memory usage(2.6 GB).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/the-mysterious-lost-memory-which-belongs-to-no-process/ if no process consumes lost memroy. For the various columns in Task Manager see https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/windows-10-memory-compression-and-more/. Task Manager shows Active Memory which is an extra category in ETW when you really want to find where your memory is hiding.

Comment: @AloisKraus I read the above links, but I still couldn't resolve where is hidden memory in the "In use" section and it belongs to who?

Comment: You can use vmmap https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap and analyze the memory usage with it. What does it tell you? A screenshot would help or the saved vmmap file when it has 10 GB and later when it has 60 GB. If the process has no visible leak then use Rammap to see where the system accounts the memory to.

Comment: @AloisKraus, ok I will upload rammap snapshot tomorrow, thank you